# numpy where - how to set condition on whole column?

Tags: python, numpy

How to implement :

```
t=np.where(<exists at least 1 zero in the same column of t>,t,np.zeros_like(t))
```

in the "pythonic" way?

this code should set all column to zero in t if t has at least 1 zero in that column

Example :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 1
```

should turn to

```
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Forget about the `where` for the moment.  How do you test `t` for 0s?  And then apply a `any` column wise?  Give us a sample `t`, and apply those tests.  Then we can help with the nest step(s).

Comment: @hpaulj see example in the edit

Comment: `~(a == 0).any(0, keepdims=True) * a` or `(a != 0).all(0, keepdims=True) * a`

Answer (score 1):

`any` is what you need

`~(arr == 0).any(0, keepdims=True) * arr`

```
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: any() returns true if any element in t is zero, and then it pick t elements always which enetually ends up being a no-op

Comment: `exists at least 1 zero` isn't that saying if any of the values are 0 then t. Maybe you should provide an example

Comment: you forgot "in the same column", see example in the edit @Kenan

Comment: I think `keepdims=True` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

> this code should set all column to zero in `t` if `t` has at least 1 zero
>   in that column

The simplest way to do this particular task:

```
t * t.min(0)
```

A more general way to do it (in case you have an array with different values and the condition is: if a column has at least one occurrence of some_value, then set that column to some_value).

```
cond = (arr == some_value).any(0)
arr[:, cond] = some_value
```